# Why Running Multiple Data Scraping Tasks Take More Time Asynchronsly In Comparsion To Individually?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer in Node.JS to run a data scraping task which tries to get data from multiple pages at once. Each page has a Tabbed structure which I need to get the data from 4 tabs. I click a tab and use "await" to get the data from the tab. At the end, I write the obtained data into an excel files. The code works correctly except the time it takes to be finished.
If I run the code for a individual URL, it takes 7 to 10 seconds to get and write data into excel files for each URL. But if I run the code for 16 URLS in a "for" loop, it takes almost 30 to 33 seconds. I think it should take lower than 12 seconds to finish the job, because it is running asynchronously. During running 16 tasks in a for loop, all the threads in the CPU are occupied 100%. The code is too long, so I just write the code structure here:

since I did not know how to repeat a task if it fails, I write 2 try-catch structure as they are nested.

```
for (i = 0; i < URL.length; i++) {
    try {
        UpdateTable(URL[i], i, 1);
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            UpdateTable(URL[i], i, 2);
        } catch (e) {
            UpdateTable(URL[i], i, 3);
        }
    }
}
```

```
async function UpdateTable(URL, ii, Ind) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var temp = [];
        temp = (async () => {
            console.time(("i: " + ii + ": " + Ind).toString());
            console.timeLog("i: " + ii + ": " + Ind);
            try {
                const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
                const page = await browser.newPage();
                await page.goto(URL); //Bourse


                //Tab 1:
                await page.evaluate(() => {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('torq')[0].click();
                })
                await page.waitForSelector("tr.ev", {visible: true}).then(() => {
                });

                var temp = [];
                var temp_1col = [];
                var temp1_1col = [];
                temp = await page.evaluate(() => {
                //
                //
                //
                //
                //
                }
                
                
                //Tab 2:
                await page.evaluate(() => {
                    document.getElementsByClassName('vio')[0].click();
                })
                await page.waitForSelector("div.CalMon", {visible: true}).then(() => {
                });

                var temp1 = [];
                temp1 = await page.evaluate(() => {
                //
                //
                //
                //
                //
                }
                
                
                //Tab 3:
                await page.evaluate(() => {
                    document.querySelectorAll('a.re')[0].click();
                })
                var tt = await page.evaluate(() => {
                    return document.getElementById("d12").innerText;
                })

                while (tt === undefined || tt === "") {
                    tt = await page.evaluate(() => {
                        return document.getElementById("d12").innerText;
                    })
                }

                var temp2 = [];
                temp2 = await page.evaluate(() => {
                //
                //
                //
                //
                //
                }
                
                //Tab 4:
                await page.evaluate(() => {
                    document.querySelectorAll('a.ye')[0].click();
                })
                await page.waitForXPath("//div[@class='Main']//span//tr[5]//td[2]", {visible: true}).then(() => {
                });

                var temp4 = await page.evaluate(() => {
                //
                //
                //
                //
                //
                }
                
                
                //Writing to Excel file Using: "exceljs" module:
                const sheet8 = workbook3.addWorksheet("Adjusted");
                sheet8.views = [{rightToLeft: true}];
                sheet8.addRows(temp_adj);
                
                await browser.close();
                console.timeEnd(("i: " + ii + ": " + Ind).toString());
                return temp;
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("Error In: " + URL);
            }
        })();
    });
}
```

I measured the time that each loops take to complete:

```
i: 0: 1: 0.065ms
i: 1: 1: 0.020ms
i: 2: 1: 0.004ms
i: 3: 1: 0.004ms
i: 4: 1: 0.028ms
i: 5: 1: 0.007ms
i: 6: 1: 0.003ms
i: 7: 1: 0.018ms
i: 8: 1: 0.018ms
i: 9: 1: 0.005ms
i: 10: 1: 0.003ms
i: 11: 1: 0.003ms
i: 12: 1: 0.003ms
i: 13: 1: 0.003ms
i: 14: 1: 0.003ms
i: 15: 1: 0.003ms
i: 13: 1: 13728.609ms
i: 0: 1: 14846.398ms
i: 15: 1: 14857.476ms
i: 4: 1: 18383.652ms
i: 6: 1: 18504.466ms
i: 10: 1: 22255.862ms
i: 5: 1: 29188.227ms
i: 7: 1: 29187.398ms
i: 14: 1: 30093.722ms
i: 8: 1: 30297.994ms
i: 2: 1: 30381.256ms
i: 1: 1: 30426.768ms
i: 11: 1: 30644.432ms
i: 12: 1: 30677.942ms
i: 3: 1: 30689.566ms
i: 9: 1: 30710.694ms
```

As you see in time log, the URL[13] takes 13728.609ms while if I run the code for this URL, it just takes  8000 ms. Why running 16 tasks together takes more time in comparison to individual task? and why it takes 30710.694ms to run asynchronously while the maximum time a task takes is lower than 10000ms?

I would be thankful if you could help me about this challenge.

Comment: What if you do not lanch several browsers but just create new pages in the same browser?

Comment: I checked it: "browser.newPage();" opens a new tab: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/48554636/13864833;
Could you please describe your idea more?

Comment: I mean what if you eliminate this call: `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});` and just reuse the single browser? You can pass it to the function or make it global variable.

Comment: I read puppeteer docs. As I understand from this [doc](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.3.0/docs/api.md#puppeteerlaunchoptions), 'puppeteer.launch' is just used to set the properties of browser and it does not open the browser. By the way, I tested what you suggested and passed the 'browser' as in input to the functions, but it causes error. Could you please have a look at the doc? Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: `puppeteer.launch()` does launch a browser instance and set its properties. You can see in some process manager. Try `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});` before the loop and use `UpdateTable(URL, ii, Ind, browser)`.

Comment: I tried, but I received this error:
`(node:16792) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: browser.newPage is not a function
`

Comment: Can you add the appropriate fragments to an update in the question?

Comment: yes, I edited my question and added the structure of the "UpdateTable" function.

Comment: Sorry, I mean something like this: `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true}); for (i = 0; i < URL.length; i++) { /*...*/  UpdateTable(URL, ii, Ind, browser); } /*...*/ async function UpdateTable(URL, ii, Ind, browser) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: Thanks for your point. I applied what you mentioned. Now the browser is opened outside the loop and every URL is opened in a New Tab, instead of a New Chrome App. Of course less memory is consumed but another challenge is showed up. When multiple URLs of the site are opened,  it seems the site server does not respond and the opened URLs are stopped at the first tab. If I open the URLs in separate Chrome App, everything is OK and even if I run the code for URLs in series again everything is OK. But if the code opens the URLs in parallel (I mean in separate New Tabs), the URLs are paused.

Comment: This may be the issue with background throttling. See some reports and possible solutions here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/search?l=Markdown&q=throttling&type=issues  If nothing helps then maybe my suggestion is not applicable to your case. I am sorry I cannot suggest something else(

Comment: The site that I am going to scrape is a dynamic site. It means when puppeteer opens the site, the main structure loads completely, but within numbers load after some seconds. When the code opens multiple tabs for different URLs, the structure is loaded but the content is not loaded at all, even after 200 seconds. At the same time, when I open that link in chrome by myself, it works correctly. It seems that the site does not serves the puppeteer when multiple tabs at the same time are opened.

Comment: I considered all the points that are mentioned here, but there was another challenge: New Tabs which were opened in parallel got stock. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60748768/puppeteer-parallel-scraping-via-multiple-pages) and now the code works correctly.  The time and the consumed RAM to scrape 19 URLs in parallel  are:
"using New Chrome Apps: 41 sec and 5.3GB" and
"using New Chrome Tabs: 37 sec and 4.4GB".
 10% decrease in time and 17% decrease in RAM consumption. I am really thankful to all of you. But still there is long long difference between 10  and 37 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I observed memory running out and the system starts swapping. Moving data between memory and disk is slow and it quickly reached the point where it seemed like it would take forever to finish. CPU utilization at 100% is good, but watch out for how much memory is used too.

Comment: Based on your point, I checked the Ram. Before starting the task, the occupied Ram is 7.8GB and during running the task, it reached up to 12.2 GB. The installed Ram is 16GB but the Ram is occupying gradually in a smooth manner and after finishing the task, it drops down suddenly to 7.8 GB.
I increased the number of URLs from 16 to 19 and now the task takes 41103.325ms which it means the time efficiency gets worse.